# C++ check if path is outside a given directory

Tags: c++, security, path, filesystems

What is the simplest way to check if a given path A is outside another path B?
I.e.: determine whether `foo/../../bar/` is outside `foo/`.

Comment: You can include C libraries in C++ as well, C solutions almost always work for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Also note that both paths should exist.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

bool isSafePath(const std::filesystem::path &root, const std::filesystem::path &child) {
    auto const normRoot = std::filesystem::canonical(root);
    auto const normChild = std::filesystem::canonical(child);
    
    auto itr = std::search(normChild.begin(), normChild.end(), 
                           normRoot.begin(), normRoot.end());
    
    return itr == normChild.begin();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(isSafePath("www/root/nvevg", "www/root/nvevg/../../../www/root/nvevg/index.html"));
    assert(isSafePath("www/root/nvevg", "www/root/nvevg/../../../www/root/nvevg"));
    assert(isSafePath("/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/", "/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/../apps/CMakeLists.txt"));
    
    assert(not isSafePath("/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/", "/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/../../../../../etc/shadow"));
    assert(not isSafePath("/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/", "/home/nvevg/projects/davshare/apps/../CMakeLists.txt"));
    assert(not isSafePath("www/root/nvevg", "www/root/nvevg/../../../www/root/"));
    assert(not isSafePath("www/root/nvevg", "www/root/nvevg/../../../www/"));
    assert(not isSafePath("www/root/nvevg", "www/root/nvevg/../../../../../../../../../etc/fstab"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could `std::filesystem::path::lexically_relative` be used to get around the existing path constraint?

Comment: @qz- if I get this right, it can't -  it just gives you a path relative to the base without any normalization (i.e. not resolving any dot-dots/dot path components), but to have the path normalized by std::filesystem::canonical() path should be existent. So you still have to find out whether these dot-dots leads somewhere outside the root or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function that returns the relative path between the passed two, called *[relative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative)*. You can check if the result path starts with `..`

```
bool isSubPath(const std::string& base, const std::string& destination)
{
    std::string relative = std::filesystem::relative(destination, base);
    // Size check for a "." result.
    // If the path starts with "..", it's not a subdirectory.
    return relative.size() == 1 || relative[0] != '.' && relative[1] != '.';
}
```