# How to check if path is a subdirectory of another

Tags: c

How I can check if path is a sub-directory of another ?
I want to check this because I don't want to allow the user to go forward of the path given as argv of my program.

I did that :

```
bool can_move(char *base, char *new)
{
    return (strncmp(base, new, strlen(base)) == 0
    && (access(new, F_OK) == 0));
}
```

But the problem is how can I mange the './' and the '../' ?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempts to solve this problem on your own, and where you got stuck. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: use strncmp ? Now if you have to manage things like "/./" or "/../" or even symlic, it's another story.

Comment: Similar question, but not duplicate because this is about C++ and the answers uses C++ library: [security - C++ check if path is in another path - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144806/c-check-if-path-is-in-another-path)

Answer (score 1):

Get the realpath() for argument and path where the user want to go .
Be sure that user realpath() is argument realpath() or start with argument realpath()/

Comment: realpath replace .. and . in strings.